# Error Unused argument for dplyr functions

Tags: r

why am I getting the following error:

Error in rename(., crop = type) : unused argument (crop = type)

It only works when I rewrite dplyr::rename(crop=type)

Comment: This means you’ve attached another package that also exports a `rename` function (or you’ve otherwise defined such a function), and that gets found instead of ‘dplyr’s.

Comment: @KonradRudolph is it possible to know which package that is?

Comment: `find("rename")`